# Transfer, edit and access files from 2018 ipad >onto pc with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: file-sharing

How would I transfer files (note taking data files, audio from lectures, etc) from 2018 ipad to my home pc running ubuntu 18.04, and can I open these files on my PC and edit them further or at least store them and play them on my pc?
Before I purchase the 2018 ipad (I am returning to college after a long absence) I need to know that this is possible. I am considering ipad apps like Notability, Goodnotes, MyScriptNow, Noteshelf, Whink. Can anybody recommend an ipad app that would let me sync audio from lectures with annotated pdf's from professors?
Can you recommend an app for 2018 ipad and for home pc with ubuntu that would let me do this?

Comment: P.S. I also have Windows 7 on the same pc with ubuntu, but I don't know if I can/need to run them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transfer it over iCloud storage. Sync the file over to iCloud storage and download them from iCloud in Ubuntu. https://www.icloud.com/

Just tried by simply connecting iPhone 6+ to Ubuntu 18.04, iPhone prompted for me to trust or not trust the connection. Selecting trust requires entering of the iPhone PIN. After connection is establish, all non-protected content is accessible via Ubuntu file manager by simply click on the left tap that say "Document on

[image]

There it shows that music memo app is sharing the recorded memo. So it depends if the app you are using to record the lectures is sharing the files or not.